# Запрос на UPDATE с указанием нескольких таблиц и изменением одного столбца

Tags: sql, oracle

Не могу изменить значение в столбце сразу в нескольких таблицах. Всю суть отражает запрос:

```
update 
(select table_name 
   from ALL_TABLES 
  where owner = 'SCHEMA_USER' 
    and TABLE_NAME like 'Table_%')
set element_id = 2 where element_id = 1;
```

Но этот запрос не рабочий.

Существует множество таблиц:

```
таблица_1
---------
element_ id | value
1           | value
1           | value
1           | value

таблица_2
---------
element_ id | value
1           | value
1           | value
1           | value
```

Необходимо сделать вот так одним запросом:

```
таблица_1
---------
element_ id | value
2           | value
2           | value
2           | value

таблица_2
---------
element_ id | value
2           | value
2           | value
2           | value
```

Comment: Один запрос может изменять только одну таблицу. На основе запроса, возвращающего имена таблиц, вам надо динамически создать нужные update запросы и выполнить их

Comment: Из мануала: *Use the UPDATE statement to change existing values in a table or in the base table of a view or the master table of a materialized view.* Обрати внимание - везде слово *table* присутствует исключительно в единственном числе.

Comment: @mike а нельзя ли как нибудь извернутся через редактируемые view ?

Comment: @Viktorov Можно, только в instead of триггере этой view придется написать те самые отдельные апдейты на все таблицы по очереди

Answer (score 4):

Так сделать нельзя. Запрос на изменение данных (см. [*DML table expression clause* в *UPDATE*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10008.htm#SQLRF01708)) допускает указание **только одной таблицы**. В случае с представлением или подзапросом - изменить можно **только одну базовую таблицу**.

Если изменяемые таблицы заранее не известны, то возможные пути решения:

- генерировать статические запросы на изменение в виде блока или скрипта и сразу же их выполнять
- формировать запросы на изменение динамически и выполнять их с [*execute immediate*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317)

---

Если такой вопрос возник, то может имеет смысл изменить дизайн БД. Посмотреть, не содержат ли изменяемые таблицы схожие данные, и если да, то объединить их в одну таблицу. То есть просто, добавить новую колонку, которая отобразит смысл свойства вложенного сейчас в имена таблиц.